# In Stata, how do I access results of mixed command?

Tags: stata

Running manual example of `mixed` command in Stata:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/pig
mixed weight week || id:
```

I get following results:

```
Performing EM optimization: 

Performing gradient-based optimization: 

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1014.9268  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1014.9268  

Computing standard errors:

Mixed-effects ML regression                     Number of obs      =       432
Group variable: id                              Number of groups   =        48

                                                Obs per group: min =         9
                                                               avg =       9.0
                                                               max =         9


                                                Wald chi2(1)       =  25337.49
Log likelihood = -1014.9268                     Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |   6.209896   .0390124   159.18   0.000     6.133433    6.286359
       _cons |   19.35561   .5974059    32.40   0.000     18.18472    20.52651
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
id: Identity                 |
                  var(_cons) |   14.81751   3.124226      9.801716    22.40002
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
               var(Residual) |   4.383264   .3163348      3.805112     5.04926
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. linear regression: chibar2(01) =   472.65 Prob >= chibar2 = 0.0000
```

My question is - can I programmatically access the estimates of 'Random-effects Parameters': `var(_cons)` and `var(Residual)`?

I tried going over `return(list)` & `ereturn(list)` but they don't seem to be available there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one option on the UCLA's [website](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/diparm.htm):

```
* var(cons)
_diparm lns1_1_1, f(exp(@)^2) d(2*exp(@)^2)

* var(Residual)
_diparm lnsig_e, f(exp(@)^2) d(2*exp(@)^2)
```

Comment: Great. `_diparm` is also how I would do it. It's probably worth adding that the random effect parameters can all be found in `e(b)`, albeit in different mathmetical forms, under names starting with _lns_.